# MongoDB update a mean

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to cache a mean  order to avoid retrieving all ratings and avoid aggreagtion (since the mean is to be obtained often):
This is basically what I would do:

```
Product.findOne _id: id, (prod) ->
  prod.mean = (prod.rate_count * prod.mean + rateCasted) / (prod.rating_count + 1)
  prod.rate_count++
  prod.save()
```

Problem: this implies loading the Product into the app, which I don't wanna do (performance, concurrent vote casting...)

**So how do I do it with a single `update` operation?**

Comment: you are wanting to update the product without retrieving the full object?

Comment: Wihtout retrieving it at all. I know of `select`. I just want one update request please :)

Comment: Instead of storing the mean in your doc, why not store the count and the total? Then you can increment count by 1 and increment total by `rateCasted` atomically.

Comment: If you're using Mongoose, like it seems, there's no way for you not to load the whole Product object anyway. You *must* load it to update it!

Comment: @arun better solution than mine. Thank you!

Comment: @Qualcuno there is the `Product.update`, isn't it?

Comment: @arun what should I when the user is modifying his rating?

Comment: I believe you would already know the user rating if the user is modifying it (otherwise you have to do a separate query to check if the user has already rated and get their old rating). Then simply increment the total by the difference (i.e. new rating minus old rating) and do not update the count.

Comment: @arun I was using update method with upsert set to true and then I checked the result to know whether it was an upsert or not. That part I gonna change then

Comment: @Vinz243 Use findAndModify (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) and get the old document. If no old doc exists, then you know it is a new rating. If old doc has a rating, then take the diff.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it with Mongoose and keep it in model if you want. the [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) method updates the model and does not return it back.

Comment: Thank you, but I knew f the update method; The problem is tha the update is not just an $inc, it is also basedon other fields such as rating_counts